# Keyframes won't respond to 'Cycles' f-curve modifier

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I'm making some material tests with Mapping nodes, but the Y scale of one of the Mapping nodes won't respond to the Cycles modifier. The other values do respond to modifiers but these won't:

[image: oofed curves]

I'm not really use why this is happening, perhaps it's an easy fix and I don't know about it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Cycles* f-curve modifier *is* working, but you have a keyframe on frame 4335 which is being included in the modifier. This means any repetitions of those keyframes are happening *after* frame 4335. If you zoom very far out after adding the modifier you can see that.

I presume you actually want that keyframe to be on frame 105 as that causes creates the same repeating pattern as the *X Scale* channel.

Comment: How did a keyframe ended up there xD? Thanks